# Node.js receives POST request yet gives client side error

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am successfully sending POST requests to a node.js server running on port 8080 via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: 'test'
});
```

I than can read and work with the data server side using event listeners on the request:

```
request.setEncoding('utf8');

request.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
   console.log(chunk);
});

request.addListener('end', function() {
   response.end();
});
```

However I still get an error on my client side like the AJAX call was unsuccessful. The error I get is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I also noticed that there is no response and the headers are missing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From which page are you sending the ajax requests? It needs to be on the same domain as the server - try using a relative URL and hosting the client page on the same server and port.

Comment: I send the ajax requests from http://127.0.0.1/projectname/index.html, it should be the same domin as the server?

Comment: Then the requests will be from `127.0.0.1:80` (default HTTP) and the response from `:8080`. These are different origins. One solution is to have node serve up the page, for example `127.0.0.1:8080/index.html` (which would mean altering your node code). 

Or you can look at JSONP if you want to keep the client-serving server and backend server separate.

Comment: I have tried sending the data as JSONP but than I get another error and node cannot read the request. The error I get is: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Comment: Then you need to add the request or response `content-type` as `application/json`

Comment: I added response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); to my server side code. That removed the errors on the client side, but now node cannot read the (jsonp) data.

Comment: @EMMERICH, JSON-P should be sent as `application/javascript`.  It is not JSON.

Comment: In the end I decided to rewrite the app so that node now servers all the pages. This way the whole thing works perfectly. Your answer is still correct as it decried what the original problem and solution would be.